# ModalDirective causing error in Angular Universal

Tags: ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I have a `ModalDirective` from `ngx-bootstrap` version 1.9.3 and am using Angular 4. When a call is made to `show()` when code is executing on the server side (I am using Angular Universal), I am getting the following exception:

```
Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
at ModalDirective.checkScrollbar (ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:49156:105)
at ModalDirective.show (ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:48977:14)
at ConfirmModalComponent.show (ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:48086:27)
at SafeSubscriber._error (ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:87270:41)
at SafeSubscriber.module.exports.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:574:16)
at SafeSubscriber.module.exports.SafeSubscriber.error (ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:533:26)
at Subscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._error (ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:464:26)
at Subscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.error (ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:438:18)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._error (ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:464:26)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.error (ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:438:18)
```

Is the code not built to support Angular Universal or is there something I need to do in order to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Please update ngx-bootstrap to 2.0.0-beta.8, it supports Angular Universal.

Comment: I already tried this and it has exactly the same issue:

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/modal/modal.directive.ts#L399

Comment: hmm, I don't see this error on our universal demo - https://ngx-universal.herokuapp.com/modals

Comment: Could you create a repo with minimal reproduction? I'll reopen github issue then.

Comment: Sure.  I'll ping you when I have updated the question with a repo.